# Any cruisecontrol plugins for Dimensions CM

Tags: cruisecontrol, dimensions

Sources codes are managed with Dimension CM, and now I wanna setup the continuous integration environment with CruiseControl. But the problem is I cannot find any support for Dimensions CM. Do any guys know how can the CruiseControl be configured to know the repository changed or is there any other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There definitely is a plugin. Unfortunately we have a seperate Configuration Management team and I don't know for sure where they got it from. I think that it would have been from Serena.

I received these files:

commons-logging-api.jar
darius.jar
dmclient.jar
dmfile.jar
dmnet.jar
dmtpi.jar

with instructions to copy them to CruiseControl\lib

Chapter 17 of the Dimensions CM Build Tools User's Guide gives the details.

In the CruiseControl config.xml configuration file. You will need to add the following
elements:

At top level within the  tags add

`<plugin name="dimensions" classname="com.serena.dmtpi.DimensionsSourceControl" />`

In the project

```
<modificationset quietperiod="30">
```

`<dimensions userID="user" password="passwd"
database="db" server="server" project="project" path="" />`

`</modificationset>`

I hope that helps, I know how frustrating it is trying to get any information at all about this.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Well, if google won't find a plugin for you (and it surely looks as if [cruisecontrol](http://cruisecontrol.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cruisecontrol/trunk/cruisecontrol/main/src/net/sourceforge/cruisecontrol/sourcecontrols/) does not have the SCM plugin you need), you can always contribute your own. Have a look at the [StarTeam's contrib plugin](http://cruisecontrol.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cruisecontrol/trunk/cruisecontrol/contrib/plugins/StarTeam/) to get an idea of direction